# Error while resizing partition before installation of Ubuntu. How can I get my data back?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, ntfs, data-recovery

It was a ~22 GBytes first windows partition (with loader). I wanted to split it on 2: 13 GB and 9 GB. In the middle of process was an error with something similar to "unable to write data on media (on disk?)".

After this I got 2 partitions:

Windows ntfs partition with remark:    (used space unknown).
Unused space

This is what it looks like now:
[image: Partition table at installation]

At this point I've stopped everything and came here.

(It seems that windows cannot start. But I didn't try too much.
I can't be sure that all my files were successfully transferred to the resized partition.)

When I am trying to mount partition from Ubuntu it says:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/ubuntu/CE00475C00474AA3:
  Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda1" "/media/ubuntu/CE00475C00474AA3"'
  exited with non-zero exit status 13: Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
highest_vcn = 0x607c, last_vcn - 1 = 0xa2bf
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Now I am using Internet from Live-DVD. And it is a real pain, because it takes ~20 minutes to boot from Live-DVD. (I don't know why) What should I do now?

http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/286ikp/error_while_resizing_partition_before/

Comment: Again me. Runned chkdsk /f lost 4 GB of data and got a bunch of file0268.chk files. Windows installation completely unusable now. Can't install ubuntu either.